# Cake PHP Translate Behavior, multiple field anomaly?

Tags: cakephp, translation, cakephp-3.0

I use the core translator of CakePHP and i have an anomaly.
I have an application with 90 tables. 80 tables have at least on field to translate. Some tables have more than one field.
All tables have just few records (i'm in development step)
I have no problem in my application with all tables with only one field to translate but when i use tables with more than one field to translate, it seems that i have an infinite loop with at then end a problem of memory.

Exemple of a code 
MarketsTable.php

```
class MarketsTable extends BaseTable {
    public function initialize(array $config){
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('markets');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['name_lang','description_lang']]);
    }
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['name_lang']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['language_id'], 'Languages'));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Market.php

```
class Market extends EntityBase{
    use LazyLoadEntityTrait;
    use TranslateTrait;

    protected $_accessible = ['*' => true,'id' => false];
}
```

And finally i have a little thing very strange, but i imagine some specialist of PHP will explain me it. I found a "solution" to solve my problem.
If i a line of code in the class TranslateBehavior, the problem doesn't exist any more (the code start at the line 207 of TranslateBehavior.php)

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, $options){
    $locale = $this->locale();
    if ($locale === $this->getConfig('defaultLocale')) {
        return;
    }
    $conditions = function ($field, $locale, $query, $select) {
        return function ($q) use ($field, $locale, $query, $select) {
            $q->where([$q->repository()->aliasField('locale') => $locale]);
            if ($query->isAutoFieldsEnabled() || in_array($field, $select, true) || in_array($this->_table->aliasField($field), $select, true)) {
                $q->select(['id', 'content']);
            }
            // line added by myself
            $q->__toString();
            return $q;
        };
    };
    // ...
}
```

How this line "$q->__toString();"can solve my problem ???? :s

Comment: How can anyone reproduce this problem without creating dozens of tables and hoping for the best? In what situation exactly (code wise) does the problem actually occur? Please try to create an example with the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the issue, and please also mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: My CakePHP version is 3.4.13. I will try to make the same test with only one table and i will tell you.